# Find the perimeter of the given trapezoid

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, problem-solving

> Find the perimeter of the given trapezoid

[image]

(The diagram is not drawn to scale)

I thought I could use the pythagorean theorem, but I have two unknow sides. What do I do now??

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's an isosceles trapezoid: Draw another height with length $6$. The bottom will be $2x+3$ which is $8$. While $x=5/2$ it is not difficult to see you have $5k-12k-13k$ triangle. So the hypotenuse will be $13/2$. Now you can calculate the perimeter.

Comment: How did you get $2x$? I do not understand why they both share the same variable. Also i don't understand how you got $5k - 12k - 13k$

Comment: I assumed it, otherwise no solution.

Comment: I see.. @nikamed